# How to create a SVN Server on Windows XP machine without admin rights?

Tags: svn

We have a Windows XP machine in our team and is used as a gateway. We do not have admin rights of that machine as it is managed by some other team. What we would like to do is to create a SVN Server on this machine using the non admin user that we already have. Is it possible? Is there any exploded version of SVN Server which we can run from command prompt?

Your help would really be appreciated in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are at least 3 things wrong with your configuration before we even get to the point where one might actually get the service online.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply run `svnserve` from the command line. Without admin mode, you can't create a service, so it has to be started manually each time.

However, why do you want to use another team's server? And why a gateway server? And XP? XP is no longer under Microsoft support. Time to get Windows 7 or 8.

If you need Subversion, get a server for Subversion and get it configured correctly. Server prices are so low now-a-days, that getting a correctly configured server for a team of developers should n longer be a problem. This is especially true that most sites now use virtual servers and could configure one out of thin air.

A Subversion server (especially one running `svnserve`) doesn't take much in the way of hardware. You don't need a whole lot of memory or a really fast processor. The big limiting part of Subversion is network bandwidth, and even that isn't such a great need. You will need to make sure that Port 3691 (the port that svnserve uses) isn't blocked by your routers. Getting that to work may be the biggest headache some sites have with using Subversion's `svnserve`.

Answer (score 0):

[Svnserve](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html), without daemon mode.